# jquerymobile and leaflet method not work

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I created a simple app for Android. I have an error: "script error : $jq('#map'). panTo is not a function"
I tried so many changes but the error remains. where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance.
The code is:

```js
<script>
    //Called after application is started.
    function OnStart()
    {
        
         var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
          maxZoom: 18,
          attribution: osmAttrib
      });
      var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2).addLayer(osm);
      marker= L.marker(map.getCenter()).addTo(map)//.bindPopup("<b>Actual Position</b>").openPopup();
      
    loc = app.CreateLocator( "GPS,Network" );
 loc.SetOnChange( loc_OnChange ); 
 loc.SetRate( 0.2 ); //10 seconds.
 loc.Start();

    sns = app.CreateSensor( "Accelerometer" );
    sns.SetOnChange( sns_OnChange );
    sns.Start();
    
    }
    
    //Called when we get a change in location.
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
function loc_OnChange( data )
{

 $jq('#field_GPS').text( data.provider);
 $jq('#field_GPS').append("<br>Lat "+data.latitude+", Lng "+data.longitude 
  +", Alt "+data.altitude);
 $jq('#field_GPS').append("<br>Spd "+data.speed+", Bear "+data.bearing
  +", Accu "+data.accuracy);
  

  marker.setLatLng([data.latitude, data.longitude ]).update();
  $jq('#map').panTo(marker.getLatLng, 8, {animation: true});
 // map.panTo([50, 30]);
  //$('#map').fitBounds(marker.getBounds());
}

function sns_OnChange( x, y, z, time )
{
    $jq('#field_ACC').text( "x="+x + "\n y="+y + "\n z="+z );
}


</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src='file:///android_asset/app.js'></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    
 
 //<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/1B74BD89-2A22-4B93-B451-1C9E1052A0EC/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    //<script src="/vendor/leaflet/addons/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
    //<script src="/vendor/leaflet/addons/leaflet.hash.js"></script>
    //<script src="/vendor/leaflet/addons/leaflet.makimarkers.js"></script>
    //<script src="/vendor/leaflet/addons/leaflet.listmarkers.min.js"></script>
    //<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/leaflet/addons/css/leaflet.markercluster.css" />
</head>
 
<style>
 body { background-color: #ffffff; }
    .hello 
    { 
        font-size: 42; 
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        color: blue;
    }
    
    #map {
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
  }
</style>

<body onload="app.Start()">

 <div data-role="page">

 <div data-role="header">
  <h1 style="text-align:center;">Traking Sensor</h1>
 </div><!-- /header -->

 <div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <div id="field_GPS">GPS GOES HERE</div>
  <div id="field_ACC" style="color:#0000FF">ACCELEROMETER GOES HERE</div>
  <div id='map'></div>
 </div><!-- /content -->

 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <h4 style="text-align:center;">Ing. Marco Salvatori</h4>
 </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is indeed no method _panTo_ in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/?s=panto – panTo is a method of Google Maps, not jQuery

Comment: what is a method like panTo for leaflet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`panTo` is a method on Leaflet map instances, but you are using it as a jQuery method - `$jq('#map').panTo`. You should just be using `map.panTo`.

Please see http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-panto for full documentation on this and other Leaflet methods.

Comment: getLatLng is a method on leaflet markers, therefore you need a () after it

Comment: i try "map.panTo(marker.getLatLng(), 8, {animation: true});". I have the same error.

Comment: panTo takes two parameters, while you are giving it three. Check docs at http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#pan-options

Comment: i try 1,2,3 parameter but i have always the same error!! for example i try "map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());". it's possible I forgot a reference?

Comment: isnt your `marker` outside of the scope of its function...you use it in `loc_OnChange` but its declared/initialized in `OnStart`...

Comment: i try "map.panTo(new L.LatLng(40.737, -73.923));" and "map.panTo([data.latitude, data.longitude]);". always error...

Comment: can you put this in a fully contained test site or jsfiddle so we can see it in action.

Comment: you have a `Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined` on load

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing "head tags". where it must be put into jsfiddle?

Comment: no idea? without the single istruction, the app work well.

Comment: your jsfiddle references `app`, yet the fiddle as it stands has no idea what `app` is - you need to bring it in somehow before we can debug more.

Comment: ok. I solved. the offending statement was changed from "var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2).addLayer(osm);" in "map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2).addLayer(osm);"